# Using large index in python (numpy or lists)

Tags: python, numpy

I frequently need to enter large integers for indexing and creating numpy arrays, such as 3500000 or 250000.  Normally I'd enter these using scientific notation, 3.5e6 or .25e6 or such.  This is quicker, and much less likely to have errors.

Unfortunately, python expects integer datatypes for indexing.  The obvious solution is to convert datatypes.  So `[5e5:1e6]` becomes `[int(5e5):int(1e6)]`, but this decreases readability and is somewhat longer to type. Not to mention, it's easy to forget what datatype an index is until an indexing operation fails on a `list` or `numpy.ndarray`.

Is there a way to have `numpy` or python interpret large floats as integers, or is there an easy way to create large integers in python?

Comment: What kind of "errors" are you worried about?

Comment: @Stefan, mostly things like confusing `3500000` with `3500000`.

Comment: Huh? Those two are the same.

Comment: Are you using these indices in an interactive mode or are they *hard-coded* indices in your program?

Comment: Oops, so they are.  I meant to add an extra zero to one.

Comment: @wwii, I'm generally using them in interactive mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a comment you considered having `e5 = 10**5` for use as in `35*e5`, lamenting it doesn't support `3.5*e6`. Here's a hack that does:

```
class E:
    def __init__(self, e):
        self.val = 10**e
    def __rmul__(self, x):
        return int(x * self.val)
```

Demo:

```
>>> e6 = E(6)
>>> 3.5*e6
3500000
```

Though due to floats being lossy, this can lead to slight inaccurracies, for example:

```
>>> 0.1251*e6
125099
```

Here's a better hack, building the literal `'0.1251e6'` and evaluating that:

```
class E:
    def __init__(self, e):
        self.e = e
    def __rmul__(self, x):
        return int(float('%se%d' % (x, self.e)))
```

Demo:

```
>>> e6 = E(6)
>>> 0.1251*e6
125100
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're worried about mistakes in the number of zeros, try underscores.

```
>>> 3_500_000
3500000
```

Comment: I like it, it's clear and readable, although a bit verbose.  Also, it appears to only be available in python 3.6+.  Maybe it's time to upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

My cheap solution is to create a helper function in proper scope.

```
def e(coeff, exponent):
    return int (coeff * 10 ** exponent)
np_array[e(3.5,6)] # use like this
```

But this cheaper answer may cause round off error,
Create alias for int in proper scope is simple and clean solution.

```
e=int # in proper scope
```

Comment: I don't know the way to change the evaluation of literal or create reader macro in python , so I almost use helper functions to shorten a expression or a statement.

Comment: This is inaccurate, for example `e(0.1251, 6)` is 125099 instead of 125100.

Comment: Hmm... if they're willing to spend the name `e` on this and use it like that, they could also just do `e = int` and then use it like `e(3.5e6)`.

Comment: Round off error is critical for this use-case, I try to replace my answer.

Comment: Yes, I feel that what you said is nice answer. Create alias for int.

Answer (score 1):

I can propose to use such notation `[5*10**5:1*10**6]` but it's not so clear as in case of 5e5 and 1e6. And even worse in case of `3.5e6 = 35*10**5`

Comment: This is a fantastic solution, although I wouldn't dare to use it anywhere I needed to understand the indices.  It could be made a little clearer predefining some constants such as `e5 = 10**5`, `e4 = 10**4`, and so on.  That would make `3.5e6 = 35*e5`.   Only downside is there can't be a decimal place on the left hand side.

Comment: Yeah, 5*e5 is even more readable, I think. I had to come to this solution myself :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a shorter name to `int()` such as `I`

```
I = int

x = I(3.5e6)
print (x)
#3500000
```

This still allows use of `int()` normally

Comment: In this case I'm using the ipython interpreter, so I need a solution that works with typical python code.

Comment: @user2699 changed my answer

Answer (score 0):

This should fix the problems with indexing lists and arrays with floats,

```
slice_orig = slice
def slice(*args):
    return slice_orig(*[int(i) for i in args])

slice.__doc__ = slice_orig.__doc__+ """
WARNING: overridden to convert (stop, start, step) to integers"""
```

It doesn't allow using large numbers with other `numpy` functions requiring an `int` type.

EDIT: This has to be used explicitly, such as `list[slice(1e5)]`, so it's not as useful as I expected.